# Is B2B spartacus storefront going to be released by Feb/Mar 2020?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Wanted to check if we can safely assume that B2B storefront basic would be available by Feb/Mar 2020

Answer (score 2):

Information from our roadmap :

> Many B2B features depend on new APIs that are scheduled for release in SAP Commerce during Q2 2020 or later.

Please read our roadmap here: https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/spartacus-roadmap/

Comment: If we plan to start development of B2b Store front some time in April will we have the early release code by then?

Comment: It is quite hard to say at this point. We do have separate branches for new features before the release though.

Comment: Thank you Knapik, I case if delivery is delayed can we build B2B storefront in current spartacus building our own v2 for which ever features not available?

Comment: Of course you can do it, but remember that upgrading to the next Spartacus versions might be difficult if you apply some heavy changes by yourself